# Converting matrix(list) to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I need to convert format of my adjacency from list to a dictionary with following skeleton:

```
def adjmat_to_adjlist(adjmat: List\[List\[int\]\]) -\> Dict\[int, 
List\[int\]\]:
    pass
```

Here's what i got:

```
adjmat = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
 
def adjmat_to_adjlist(adjmat: List[List[int]]) -> Dict[int, List[int]]:
 
    adjlist = dict(zip(key, i) for i, key in enumerate(adjmat))
    return adjlist

print (adjmat_to_adjlist(adjmat))
```

This solution comes with error:
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'int' object is not iterable

Can someone explain me the error and propose changes to makes my code works properly?

Comment: Maybe just `dict(enumerate(adjmat))`?

Comment: i and key are iterators in my adjmat, zip creates new value in my adjlist